# Create PostgreSQL DataBase using .sql script in Java application

Tags: java, sql, database, postgresql, file

I write Java application with Database, and I need to create SQL file which will create user and database,  assign all privileges on the database to the user. (DB and user should be created before application runs)
But I can't come up with understanding how I can do it. Help pls!

Comment: Creating databases and users is the responsibility of the DBA, not of some random application. _If_ your application could do that, it would mean it uses a superuser account which you should never do from within your application.

Comment: Are you talking about setting it up once when you first install the application on a particular machine? In that case, make running the script one of the tasks of the installer.

Comment: If you are trying to create a database and schema for your application you can use flyway library which is generally used for migration support, for more details click on : https://flywaydb.org/getstarted/java . Or if its specific to user and DB creation I would suggest to run with scripts.

Comment: @ADyson, yes. For example i have primitive script with there commands 
CREATE DATABASE school;
CREATE USER maintainer;
ALTER ROLE maintainer SUPERUSER CREATEROLE CREATEDB;
How can I execute this file?

Comment: Using your installer. Like if you wanted to make a package to install this system (application + DB) on Windows, you'd make a Windows installer executable which would then do all the operations to install the application, install the database engine (if needed), and then create the database etc. If you were deploying on linux, you might do the same via a package manager service like apt-get or rpm. You will have seen this process many times yourself if you ever install software onto your computer. The installer can carry out as many commands as you need it to, automatically.